# Error when running UI Automation instrument from command line

Tags: ios, command-line, automation, instruments

I'm trying to launch my app using UI Automation from command line. here is what I'm calling

instruments -w -t /Applications/Xcode45-DP2.app/Contents/Applications/Instruments.app/Contents/PlugIns/AutomationInstrument.bundle/Contents/Resources/Automation.tracetemplate /projects/TesApp/build/Debug-iphoneos/TestApp.app

I always get this error
instruments[3613:3503] Exception encountered during 'setThrottleConstraints:' dispatch: (null)
Instruments Usage Error : Device failed to become ready for use.

Any idea what I might be doing wrong ? or even any suggestion what else I can try?

Answer (score 1):

Found it, just needed to add the Device ID.

so just used -w DEVICE_UDID

Also, one more thing that was confusing me, the app, you just need to add the name of an App that is already installed, not the local path ( as the instruments doesn't deploy the app for you)